# Get HTML value inside a textarea component using plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the HTML content of the text that is being entered inside a `<textarea>` in plain Javsacript (equivalent of `$('id').html()`). I have tried using `innerHTML` to get the HTML content but with no success.

Comment: `textarea` can not have HTML content, its content is plain text without any formatting

Comment: If don't want to use jQuery why tag your question with jQuery?

Comment: I wanted to know the equivalent of .html() in javascript.

Comment: jQuery is open source you can refer to its source code

Answer (score 2):

Textareas don't have HTML content, they have text content. You can access their current value using the `.value` property, just like most other form controls.

Answer (score 1):

So, In my understanding you  want to get the entire HTML of the text area like

`<textarea>user content</textarea>` right. so in this case you have to use `outerHtml` functionality of JavaScript. But in my opinion this is not safe to use.

**simple EX**

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="id"></textarea>
```

**js code**

```
var element = document.getElementById( 'id' );
alert( element.outerHTML ); //it gives dom element
```

See the below links:

[mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML)

[link2](http://help.dottoro.com/ljloliex.php)

[github](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/641)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('id').value
```

if 'id' is the id of the textarea element, value property is the content (as text) of the textarea.

Comment: My problem is that when I press enter button and then type, the new line is not taken care of when storing it in database. I want to convert each line into <p> tag and then store it in the db

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get it on a specific trigger (ex. click) or do you just want to print it in another part of the document. Here's a basic example :

Let's say your textarea id is is "texta" and you want to ..print that content to another another div, hidden field or whatever your heart desires. We'll name that second id "echo"

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("texta");
document.getElementById('echo')innerHtml = textarea.value;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to save the text on click of a button.

Comment: Okay, this is getting just a bit away from the original post. But you`re new and so am I. So let's do this together. For the problem you addressed Michel with, you should use the PHP function  nl2br() ;

** Sorry, pressed early Enter key.

So, for example, use this :

`$text = $_POST['textarea'];
$preserve =  nl2br($text);
echo $preserve;`

Or, in HTML, try using the <pre> </pre> tags around your textarea input;

Answer (score -1):

```
<textarea id="test_id" name="test_id"></textarea>
<input type="button" onClick="simple_func();"> 


<script type="text/javascript">
function simple_func()
{

    document.getElementById("test_id").value='hello world';
}
</script>
```

Comment: When posting code, it is great to also include an explanation of why this works and what the OP did wrong.

Answer (score -1):

So what I did was replaced every new line with a break tag. So now everything works fine and is rendered in email clients the way I wanted.